# Why will my UICollectionViewController not run with two CollectionViews?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview

So I am developing an app that requires two collection views within in one CollectionViewController.  But for some reason, whenever I run it I get the error:

> 2015-06-25 13:23:23.601 Quorum[35215:6966756] *** Assertion failure in -[Quorum.ManageListsCollectionViewController loadView], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-3347.44/UICollectionViewController.m:171
>   2015-06-25 13:23:23.604 Quorum[35215:6966756] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UICollectionViewController loadView] loaded the "5Oy-7X-AZf-view-1bs-84-zCb" nib but didn't get a UICollectionView.'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (0x183e982d8 0x1956bc0e4 0x183e98198 0x184d4ced4 0x188a57f24 0x1888d8a28 0x18898ef68 0x18898ee64 0x18898e2f0 0x18898df9c 0x18898dcbc 0x18898dc3c 0x1888d5760 0x18821de1c 0x188218884 0x188218728 0x188217ebc 0x188217c3c 0x1888cc56c 0x183e502a4 0x183e4d230 0x183e4d610 0x183d792d4 0x18d58f6fc 0x18893efac 0x10007aca8 0x195d3aa08)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Here is my CollectionViewController code:

```
import UIKit

let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"

class ManageListsCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var menuButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var ListView: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var DetailView: UICollectionView!

    let ListViewIdentifier = "ListViewCell"
    let DetailViewIdentifier = "DetailViewCell"

    let sectionInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10.0, left: 10.0, bottom: 10.0, right: 10.0)


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if self.revealViewController() != nil {
            menuButton.target = self.revealViewController()
            menuButton.action = "revealToggle:"
            self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
        }
        ListView.delegate = self
        DetailView.delegate = self

        ListView.dataSource = self
        DetailView.dataSource = self

       self.view.addSubview(ListView)
        self.view.addSubview(DetailView)





        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Register cell classes
        self.collectionView!.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

    // MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource

    override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        //#warning Incomplete method implementation -- Return the number of sections
        if collectionView == self.ListView {
            return 1
        } else{

        return 1
        }

    }


    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        //#warning Incomplete method implementation -- Return the number of items in the section
        if collectionView == self.ListView {
            return 20
        }
        return 5
    }


    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if collectionView == self.ListView {
            let cell: ListCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(ListViewIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ListCell

            // Set up cell
            return cell
        }

        else {
            let cell1: DetailCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(DetailViewIdentifier,forIndexPath: indexPath) as! DetailCell

            // ...Set up cell

            return cell1
        }
```

Comment: It seems that none of the UICollectionView instances is connected to the view property of the controller which is required when the controller is loaded via storyboard

Comment: If you need two collection views in the same view controller, I believe you need to use a normal `UIViewController` with two `UICollectionView`s. You can't use a `UICollectionViewController`.

Comment: @AdamPro13 why is this the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to have two collection views in one parent view, and you want to manage these collections using collection view controllers, you need to use controller containment. You can set this up very easily in Interface Builder.